# Pyopengl glReadPixels causes memory leak

Tags: python, memory-leaks, python-imaging-library, pyopengl

so i'm working on a python program in which i set up an (offscreen) window to draw to, and then every iteration i update the contents, and use glReadPixels to get whatever is on the window into a PNG image.

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from PIL import Image,ImageDraw,ImageOps

class someclass:
    initialized = False

    def initialize(self):
        glutInit(sys.argv)

        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB)
        glutInitWindowSize(self.width, self.height)
        glutCreateWindow(b"OpenGL Offscreen")
        glutHideWindow()
        self.initialized = True

    def new_frame(self):
        if not self.initialized:
            self.initialize()

        glClearColor(*(self.background.getfloat()), 1.0)
        glColor(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        gluOrtho2D(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0)
        glViewport(0, 0, self.width, self.height)

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
        self.handlers(None)
        glFlush()

        glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)

        data = glReadPixels(0, 0, self.width, self.height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)

        currentimage = Image.frombytes("RGBA", (self.width, self.height), data)
        currentimage = ImageOps.flip(currentimage)
        currentimage.convert('RGB').resize((self.width//self.scale,self.height//self.scale), Image.ANTIALIAS).save("something.png","PNG")
```

Every interation the new_frame() function is called. The first time the new_frame function calles the initialize function. This code works fine except for one thing: after about 40 iterations memry usage goes crazy. every iteration it adds about 50-100 mb (as seen by my system monitor) until at some point i use all of my ram. So i started doing some testing by commenting out code etc. The problem seems to be the call to glReadPixels(). When it's commented out the program doesn't eat up more and more memory. Does anyone know of an alternative, a fix or a good strategy to fix it? I really have no clue what i can do to stop it from happening. If you'd like to test the code out for yourself i could also post the github link.